# Setting custom statustext in express response using default message?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, http, response

I'm using express in my api and trying to set a custom error message as the statusText of my response to the user with the following code.

```
        return res.status(401).send('Invalid email');
```

However, instead of recieving a statusText of "Invalid email" with a 401 I recieve a "Unauthorized" and 401 when I print out the response object in my clients console. Changing the code changes the response message but its always the default one for that code.

I've tried other syntaxes like

```
    res.status(401).send({
        success: false,
        error: {
          message: 'Invalid email'
        }
      });
```

and

```
res.status(401).send({statusText: 'Invalid email'});
```

with the same result.

I use this handler beforehand.

```
app.use(express.json())
```

How can I send the text **'Invalid email'** with my response?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set the HTTP "reason phrase" - don't. It doesn't exist in HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Whats the standard practice of distinguishing between different errors that might be classified under the same error code in http/2 and http/3 if one exists?

Comment: Use the response body.